# Drupal 7: Playback of Audio Files Stored on Google Drive

Tags: audio, drupal, drupal-7, google-drive-api, audio-streaming

We're working with a client that is required to post audio of meeting minutes. Their current method of storing these audio files is Google Drive and they would prefer not to change that. As it stands, the site has links to the audio file on Google Drive which sends you to Google Drive and asks you to download the file. This is very inefficient. Does anyone know of a way to link to or stream a file hosted on Google Drive to make it more seamless or user friendly?

They are currently using WMA files, but if need be, we can request that they use MP3 or WAV. The link below will give you an idea what we're looking to improve.

Thanks in advance.

https://asbcs.az.gov/board-staff-information/meeting-dates-materials